# How iOS detects network printer automatically

Tags: ios, point-of-sale, thermal-printer, airprint, ipp-protocol

POS systems mostly can detect thermal printers automatically, as far as I know there are only two ways for an installed application on ios to do that, either by faking it as an Airprint or going with IPP protocol. Since it mostly matters for those application that your printer should be on the same network and subnet configuration and Airprint doesn't support thermal printers, I believe that could be choice that they are using. But my question is that if there is another way that they are all doing it? if not how an application on ipad(iOS) can detect those printers without any need for specific driver installation? If anyone can help me with this would be great!

Comment: AirPrint is basically built onto of [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software))

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @IPPGeek The questions is that how can I write an application for iOS such that can detect printers that are not on the Airprint printer's list(most of the thermal printers) and in a way that iOS can detect the printer without any installation. For example how applications such as square, vend and etc are detecting thermal printers whenever they are connecting either with USB or through LAN network to the iPad?

Comment: In order to detect non-AirPrint printers you need to check if the printer support discovery at all and in case it does what kind of discovery it supports. There are just to many options. What discovery method does the printer support you are trying to connect to?

Comment: It uses DHCP, The questions is how an ios application like square or vend can detect some specific thermal printers that are on the local network and they are not AirPrint printers?

Comment: DHCP ist not a protocol used for discovery. DHCP is used to assign an IP to the device. Most DHCP implementations also provide an integrated DNS service that allows you to resolve a client-name to an IP address. Discovery needs to be done before. How do you discover the name or ip of the device? Manual discovery would be: check the devices network settings e.g. on it's built in display.

Comment: @IPPNerd Hi this is interesting: "to detect non-AirPrint printers you need to check if the printer support discovery at all". Most of the printer details just display like Communications Specifications - Wireless – 802.11b/g so how to find discovery details for a non- air print printer? Is there any specific way to check before buying non-air print enable printers?

Comment: @Maulik, the network section of the technical specification should include the supported discovery protocols e.g. Bonjour, ZeroConf, mDNS, SNMP or WS Discovery. Manufacturers these days tend to advertise protocols like AirPrint and Mopria. Both protocols are based on IPP, but printer specs don't alway list IPP additionally. AirPrint and Mopria require to support discovery protocols like mDNS/Bonjour as well. Bonjour is widely supported and predates AirPrint. You can use a tool to check the supported discovery protocols, e.g. ippfind, dns-sd -Z _ipp._tcp, Discovery DNS SD Browser (Mac AppStore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print to printers from iOS you can either use the [AirPrint API](http://developer.apple.com/airprint) with [AirPrint enabled printers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311) or you can implement the printer's protocol and PDL within your own application.

Some solutions include a third middleware like component to fill the gap between the mobile app and the actual device. This is not an elegant way but seems to work for some usecases.

The full process consists indeed of two steps: discovery (like setup) and actual printing (like sending a document). With AirPrint you can check [the documentation](http://www.zeroconf.org) to learn how Bonjour aka ZeroConf works.